# Django - Custom admin page not displaying properties

Tags: django, django-admin

In my project, I use the `AbstractUser` class to override the default `User` model so I can add extra properties. I want these properties to be added to the admin page, therefore I can view them. The code below is how I have customized my admin page so far.

**forms.py**:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'following', 'posts')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'following', 'posts', )
```

**admin.py**:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = User
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'bio', 'profilePic',]



    admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

When I click on a **user** object on the admin page, I can view all the properties such as a users `username` and `email`, however I want to view properties such as `following` and `posts`, which are both `ManyToManyFields`.

I supply these properties in the `CustomUserCreationForm` and the `CustomUserChangeForm`, however I can't still view these properties.

Does anybody know how I can view these fields when I view or create a new user object? Thank you.

Comment: Did you register the new admin class?

Comment: @schillingt  Yes I have already done this by adding `admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)` in my `admin.py` file in the `users` app